# Fcm notification marked as miscellaneous

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm quite new to Firebase Cloud Messaging. And my fcm notifications are categorised as miscellaneous. Please help me out.

I have tried to create channel id but this channel is not creating but the notification is showing with default priority.

```
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCMService";
private SharedPreferences userFile;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {}

if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {              sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl() == null?null : remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl().toString());
}}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
userFile = getSharedPreferences("userFile", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
sendRegistrationToServer(token);}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {}

private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, String imageUrl) {

final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
CharSequence name = "Channel name 1";
String description = "Notification channel";
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("id 1", name, importance);                 channel.setDescription(description);     notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);                   channel.enableLights(true);                 channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);               channel.enableVibration(true);                      channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 600, 600});} 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

String channelId = "id 1";

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "id 1")     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)          .setContentTitle(title)     .setContentText(messageBody)     .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)         .setAutoCancel(true)        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setChannelId("id 1");

Intent copyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);   copyIntent.putExtra("notification_title", title); 

if (imageUrl == null) {                 notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());

} else {                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())                 .asBitmap()                 .load(imageUrl)                 .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){

                        @Override                           public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {                                    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(resource);                                 notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(resource));                                notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());}

                                @Override                           public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder){}

                            @Override                               public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable)                               {                                      super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);                                      notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());

}                       });

}}}
```